# create delete statement for multiple rows and non unique columns

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Help me to write delete statement for sqlite db

```
'rating' table schema (rID, mID, rate, pub)
```

This query will return only one tuple

```
select * from rating
where rID = 101 and mID=678 and rate = 34.5 and pub='2012-11-03'
```

All columns in table are non unique

These queries do not work

```
delete from rating where rID,mID, rate, pub in 
    (select * from rating where rID = 101 and mID=678 and rate = 34.5 and pub='2012-11-03')

delete from rating where rID=G.rID,mID=G.mID, rate=G.rate, pub=G.pub
    (select * from rating where rID = 101 and mID=678 and rate = 34.5 and pub='2012-11-03') as G
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with this?

```
delete from rating
where rID = 101 
and mID=678 
and rate = 34.5 
and pub='2012-11-03'
```

Any select statement can be converted into a delete statement that affects the same rows as those returned from the select. In fact, it's a good way to test what rows will be deleted.

Comment: It is wrong becouse first statement 'select', second 'delete'  and i need to make it in a single statement. lets make it complicated , for example i will modify query **select * from rating
where rID = 101 and mID=678 and rate = 34.5** and it will return 3 tuples with different pub. how to remove all of those tuples in single statement.

Comment: As I've said, any select can be converted to a delete; simply replace `select *` with `delete` and you will delete those same 3 tupples: `delete from rating where rID = 101 and mID=678 and rate = 34.5`. You seem to be resisting something very simple - what is your reservation?